# Fiware: can not start cygnus as service

Tags: centos7, fiware, iot, fiware-cygnus

I installed cygnus using RPMs on fiware image  CentOS-7-x64 and I can't start it as a service, Here is my logs:

```
[centos@cygnus-mongo conf]$ sudo service cygnus start
Starting cygnus (via systemctl):  Job for cygnus.service failed. See 'systemctl status cygnus.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
[centos@cygnus-mongo conf]$ sudo journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at mer. 2015-10-07 07:48:29 UTC, end at mer. 2015-10-07 10:02:35 UTC. --
oct. 07 10:02:20 cygnus-mongo.novalocal su[5700]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user cygnus
oct. 07 10:02:22 cygnus-mongo.novalocal cygnus[5695]: cat: /var/run/cygnus/cygnus_mongo.pid: No such file or directory
oct. 07 10:02:22 cygnus-mongo.novalocal cygnus[5695]: [FAILED]
oct. 07 10:02:22 cygnus-mongo.novalocal cygnus[5695]: rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/cygnus/cygnus_mongo.pid’: No such file or directory
oct. 07 10:02:22 cygnus-mongo.novalocal systemd[1]: cygnus.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
oct. 07 10:02:22 cygnus-mongo.novalocal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: cygnus.
-- Subject: Unit cygnus.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit cygnus.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
oct. 07 10:02:22 cygnus-mongo.novalocal systemd[1]: Unit cygnus.service entered failed state.
oct. 07 10:02:34 cygnus-mongo.novalocal dhclient[1064]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.111.71 port 67 (xid=0x761299ef)
oct. 07 10:02:34 cygnus-mongo.novalocal dhclient[1064]: DHCPACK from 192.168.111.71 (xid=0x761299ef)
oct. 07 10:02:35 cygnus-mongo.novalocal sudo[5774]: centos : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/cygnus/conf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xn
```

Actually the directory /var/run/cygnus was not created, is it going to be created automatically?

Here is my configuration files:

agent_mongo.conf

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = mongo-sink 
cygnusagent.channels = mongo-channel 

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mongo-channel 
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
# OrionMongoSink configuration
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMongoSink
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
# FQDN/IP:port where the MongoDB server runs (standalone case) or comma-separated list of FQDN/IP:port pairs where the MongoDB replica set members run
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_hosts = 127.0.0.1:27017
# a valid user in the MongoDB server (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username = 
# password for the user above (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password =
# prefix for the MongoDB databases
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = kura_
# prefix pro the MongoDB collections
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = kura_
# true is collection names are based on a hash, false for human redable collections
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.should_hash = false

#=============================================
# mongo-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

cygnus_instance_mongo.conf :

```
# Who to run cygnus as. Note that you may need to use root if you want
# to run cygnus in a privileged port (<1024)
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus

# Where is the config folder
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf

# Which is the config file
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_mongo.conf

# Name of the agent. The name of the agent is not trivial, since it is the base for the Flume parameters 
# naming conventions, e.g. it appears in .sources.http-source.channels=...
AGENT_NAME=cygnusagent

# Name of the logfile located at /var/log/cygnus. It is important to put the extension '.log' in order to the log rotation works properly
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log

# Administration port. Must be unique per instance
ADMIN_PORT=8081

# Polling interval (seconds) for the configuration reloading
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

Edit: add logs after lunching cygnus as a standalone application:

```
[centos@cygnus-mongo iot]$ ./cygnus.sh 
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_mongo.conf -n cygnusagent
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-0.8.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2015-10-08 15:50:32,629 (main) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication.main(CygnusApplication.java:235)] Starting a Jetty server listening on port 8081 (Management Interface)
2015-10-08 15:50:32,655 (main) [INFO - org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2015-10-08 15:50:32,656 (main) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication.main(CygnusApplication.java:238)] Starting Cygnus application
2015-10-08 15:50:32,656 (Thread-1) [INFO - org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] jetty-6.1.26
2015-10-08 15:50:32,684 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.start(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:61)] Configuration provider starting
2015-10-08 15:50:32,694 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:133)] Reloading configuration file:/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_mongo.conf
2015-10-08 15:50:32,714 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.<init>(FlumeConfiguration.java:101)] Configuration property ignored: cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username = 
2015-10-08 15:50:32,714 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:mongo-sink
2015-10-08 15:50:32,715 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:mongo-sink
2015-10-08 15:50:32,715 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.<init>(FlumeConfiguration.java:101)] Configuration property ignored: cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password = 
2015-10-08 15:50:32,715 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:930)] Added sinks: mongo-sink Agent: cygnusagent
2015-10-08 15:50:32,716 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:mongo-sink
2015-10-08 15:50:32,716 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:mongo-sink
2015-10-08 15:50:32,716 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:mongo-sink
2015-10-08 15:50:32,716 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:mongo-sink
2015-10-08 15:50:32,731 (Thread-1) [INFO - org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8081
2015-10-08 15:50:32,744 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:140)] Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [cygnusagent]
2015-10-08 15:50:32,745 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:150)] Creating channels
2015-10-08 15:50:32,758 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.DefaultChannelFactory.create(DefaultChannelFactory.java:40)] Creating instance of channel mongo-channel type memory
2015-10-08 15:50:32,765 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:205)] Created channel mongo-channel
2015-10-08 15:50:32,766 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:39)] Creating instance of source http-source, type org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
2015-10-08 15:50:32,782 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler.<init>(OrionRestHandler.java:75)] Cygnus version (0.8.2.UNKNOWN)
2015-10-08 15:50:32,808 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler.configure(OrionRestHandler.java:141)] Startup completed
2015-10-08 15:50:32,836 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:40)] Creating instance of sink: mongo-sink, type: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMongoSink
2015-10-08 15:50:32,856 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:119)] Channel mongo-channel connected to [http-source, mongo-sink]
2015-10-08 15:50:32,872 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:138)] Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{http-source=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{name:http-source,state:IDLE} }} sinkRunners:{mongo-sink=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@7caba647 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{mongo-channel=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: mongo-channel}} }
2015-10-08 15:50:32,872 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:145)] Starting Channel mongo-channel
2015-10-08 15:50:32,968 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:110)] Monitoried counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel, registered successfully.
2015-10-08 15:50:32,968 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:94)] Component type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel started
2015-10-08 15:50:32,969 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:173)] Starting Sink mongo-sink
2015-10-08 15:50:32,970 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:184)] Starting Source http-source
2015-10-08 15:50:32,972 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.initialize(GroupingInterceptor.java:92)] Grouping rules read: 
2015-10-08 15:50:32,974 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.stopAllComponents(Application.java:101)] Shutting down configuration: { sourceRunners:{http-source=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{name:http-source,state:IDLE} }} sinkRunners:{mongo-sink=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@7caba647 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{mongo-channel=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: mongo-channel}} }
2015-10-08 15:50:32,975 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.stopAllComponents(Application.java:105)] Stopping Source http-source
2015-10-08 15:50:32,978 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMongoBaseSink.start(OrionMongoBaseSink.java:139)] [mongo-sink] Startup completed
2015-10-08 15:50:32,984 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [
 - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.parseGroupingRules(GroupingInterceptor.java:165)] Error while parsing the Json-based grouping rules file. Details=null
2015-10-08 15:50:32,984 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [WARN - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.initialize(GroupingInterceptor.java:98)] Grouping rules syntax has errors
2015-10-08 15:50:33,030 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [INFO - org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] jetty-6.1.26
2015-10-08 15:50:33,081 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [INFO - org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:5050
2015-10-08 15:50:33,082 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:110)] Monitoried counter group for type: SOURCE, name: http-source, registered successfully.
2015-10-08 15:50:33,082 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-4) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:94)] Component type: SOURCE, name: http-source started
2015-10-08 15:50:33,083 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.unsupervise(LifecycleSupervisor.java:171)] Stopping component: EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{name:http-source,state:START} }
2015-10-08 15:50:33,083 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] Stopped SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:5050
2015-10-08 15:50:33,185 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:139)] Component type: SOURCE, name: http-source stopped
2015-10-08 15:50:33,185 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:145)] Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. source.start.time == 1444319433082
2015-10-08 15:50:33,185 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:151)] Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. source.stop.time == 1444319433185
2015-10-08 15:50:33,186 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append-batch.accepted == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,186 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append-batch.received == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,186 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append.accepted == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,186 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append.received == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,187 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.events.accepted == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,187 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.events.received == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,187 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.open-connection.count == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,187 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.stop(HTTPSource.java:172)] Http source http-source stopped. Metrics: SOURCE:http-source{src.events.accepted=0, src.events.received=0, src.append.accepted=0, src.append-batch.accepted=0, src.open-connection.count=0, src.append-batch.received=0, src.append.received=0}
2015-10-08 15:50:33,187 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.stopAllComponents(Application.java:115)] Stopping Sink mongo-sink
2015-10-08 15:50:33,188 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.unsupervise(LifecycleSupervisor.java:171)] Stopping component: SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@7caba647 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }
2015-10-08 15:50:33,189 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.stopAllComponents(Application.java:125)] Stopping Channel mongo-channel
2015-10-08 15:50:33,190 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.unsupervise(LifecycleSupervisor.java:171)] Stopping component: org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: mongo-channel}
2015-10-08 15:50:33,190 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:139)] Component type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel stopped
2015-10-08 15:50:33,190 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:145)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel. channel.start.time == 1444319432968
2015-10-08 15:50:33,190 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:151)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel. channel.stop.time == 1444319433190
2015-10-08 15:50:33,190 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel. channel.capacity == 1000
2015-10-08 15:50:33,190 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel. channel.current.size == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,191 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel. channel.event.put.attempt == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,191 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel. channel.event.put.success == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,191 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel. channel.event.take.attempt == 1
2015-10-08 15:50:33,191 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:167)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel. channel.event.take.success == 0
2015-10-08 15:50:33,191 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:138)] Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{http-source=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{name:http-source,state:START} }} sinkRunners:{mongo-sink=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@7caba647 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{runner.backoffs.consecutive=0} } }} channels:{mongo-channel=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: mongo-channel}} }
2015-10-08 15:50:33,191 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:145)] Starting Channel mongo-channel
2015-10-08 15:50:33,192 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-2) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:94)] Component type: CHANNEL, name: mongo-channel started
2015-10-08 15:50:33,192 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:173)] Starting Sink mongo-sink
2015-10-08 15:50:33,193 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:184)] Starting Source http-source
2015-10-08 15:50:33,193 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMongoBaseSink.start(OrionMongoBaseSink.java:139)] [mongo-sink] Startup completed
2015-10-08 15:50:33,194 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-6) [INFO - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.initialize(GroupingInterceptor.java:92)] Grouping rules read: 
2015-10-08 15:50:33,194 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-6) [ERROR - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.parseGroupingRules(GroupingInterceptor.java:165)] Error while parsing the Json-based grouping rules file. Details=null
2015-10-08 15:50:33,194 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-6) [WARN - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor.initialize(GroupingInterceptor.java:98)] Grouping rules syntax has errors
2015-10-08 15:50:33,195 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-6) [INFO - org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] jetty-6.1.26
2015-10-08 15:50:33,197 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-6) [INFO - org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:5050
2015-10-08 15:50:33,197 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-6) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:94)] Component type: SOURCE, name: http-source started
```

Answer (score 0):

Cygnus is supposed to create `/var/run/cygnus/` when started. You can check [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/develop/neore/rpm/SOURCES/init.d/cygnus#L63) the path specification, and [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/develop/neore/rpm/SOURCES/init.d/cygnus#L74) the creation and PID assignement.

I'm wondering which are the permissions of your `/var/run`... Maybe they are too restrictive for the `cygnus` user.

Anyway, are you able to run Cygnus as a standalone application (not as a service) with no errors? I mean, executing this command:

```
$ /usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_mongo.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

Comment: I updated the /var/run to the following permissions `[centos@cygnus-mongo ~]$ ls -ld /var/run/
drwxrwxrwx. 21 root root 660  7 oct.  07:48 /var/run/` but still the same error, I edited my question with logs got after lunching cygnus as a standalone application, the only error is about the grouping rule file that is empty. Thanks.